# Combine multiple EF.CompileQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Currrently EF.CompileQuery supports 5 parameters for querying.
Having said that, the EF does not support client evaluation, passing a class as a parameter to EF.CompileQuery throws (limitation / client evaluation) a bug.
I would like to understand if i can achieve atleast **12** parameters(by overloading/extending) the EF.CompileQuery for querying.
Is there any way that we can combine multiple EF.CompileQuery (2 or more queries)? Or are their any work arounds to acheive this feature.

I raised this in efcore github and this feature would be included in EF Core 5.0.0.

But I am looking for a quick workaround in 3.0.0 to support atleast **12** parameters. Please do suggest.

Many thanks.